# Mobile Hybrid application throws 500 error for all POST requests to JIRA Server

Tags: ajax, cordova, rest, mobile, jira

I have a Hybrid application using cordova and angular that utilizes the JIRA rest service. I am doing a simple call to add a comment to a JIRA ticket using ajax. **All calls were working** until the recent upgrade to JIRA 7. After the upgrade all calls except POST still succeed.

```
var data = {
            "body": "quick comment",
        };
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://our.jiraserver.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issuekey}/comment',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic garbeldygoopasdfasdf',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
            },
            data: data
        };

$http(req).then(function(response){
            console.log('success', response);
        }, function(error){
            console.log('errpr', error);
        });
```

A trimmed version of the error the server is throwing (for those TL;DR's)

1. message: "Expected authority at index 7: file://"
2. stack-trace: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected authority at index 7: file://↵ at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)↵ at com.atlassian.applinks.cors.auth.DefaultCorsService.getApplicationLinksByOrigin(DefaultCorsService.java:56)↵ at com.atlassian.applinks.cors.auth.AppLinksCorsDefaults.allowsOrigin(AppLinksCorsDefaults.java:42)↵ at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter$1.apply(XsrfResourceFilter.java:255)↵ at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter$1.apply(XsrfResourceFilter.java:252)↵ at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.indexOf(Iterators.java:778)↵ at

I will note again these calls worked until very recently...  as a workaround I setup a node/express servers to simply bounce my api calls through. I send the data there, it makes the same request and succeeds and passes the data back to my app. Of course this isn't ideal as I now have a split code base.

I went to Atlassian support who basically told be they cannot assist with third-party development.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution by now? I experience a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199303/strange-angular-rest-call-behaviour/35199657?noredirect=1#comment58117237_35199657