# Strange Angular Rest call behaviour

Tags: angularjs, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I use Angular to make a call to Atlassian JIRA's REST API. Angular is used in the context of an ionic-framework app on a device.

A `curl` as

```
curl -X POST 'https://url' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Authorization: Basic a2someStuff' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"transition": {"id": "761"}}'
```

Works and produces the desired result.

However if I perform the query using regular angular

```
curl -X POST 'https://url' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Authorization: Basic a2someStuff' -H 'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; Intellibook Build/LRX21V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"transition": {"id": "781"}}'
```

is created. I have verified that this curl works correctly **if the Header for the `User-Agent` is removed**.
Is there any possibility in angular to perform such an operation?

## edit

here the JS which generates the request:

Here the config section:

```
.constant('ApiEndpoint', {
    url: 'someUrl'
  })
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Atlassian-Token'] = 'nocheck';
  }])
```

Here the method contents:

```
var postData = '{"transition": {"id": "' + transition + '"}}';
      $http({
        url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'issue/' + issueKey + "/transitions",
        method: "POST",
        data: postData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
          //some stuff
        },
```

Comment: can you provide javascript of the angular http request ?

Comment: Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: maybe remove `'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck'` header ? in your question you dont have this one in `curl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete `User-Agent` header do it like:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['User-Agent'];
}]);
```

Here is some info about [Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for angular `$http` (see Security Considerations section)

> XSRF is an attack technique by which the attacker can trick an
>   authenticated user into unknowingly executing actions on your website.
>   Angular provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR
>   requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default,
>   XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only
>   JavaScript that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server
>   can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your
>   domain. The header will not be set for cross-domain requests.
>
> To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a
>   JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP
>   GET request. On subsequent XHR requests the server can verify that the
>   cookie matches X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header, and therefore be sure that
>   only JavaScript running on your domain could have sent the request.
>   The token must be unique for each user and must be verifiable by the
>   server (to prevent the JavaScript from making up its own tokens). We
>   recommend that the token is a digest of your site's authentication
>   cookie with a salt for added security.
>
> The name of the headers can be specified using the xsrfHeaderName and
>   xsrfCookieName properties of either $httpProvider.defaults at
>   config-time, $http.defaults at run-time, or the per-request config
>   object.
>
> In order to prevent collisions in environments where multiple Angular
>   apps share the same domain or subdomain, we recommend that each
>   application uses unique cookie name.

`xsrfHeaderName` – {string} – Name of HTTP header to populate with the XSRF token.
`xsrfCookieName` – {string} – Name of cookie containing the XSRF token.

```
$http({
        url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'issue/' + issueKey + "/transitions",
        method: "POST",
        data: postData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        xsrfHeaderName: 'XSRF-Header-Name',
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-Cookie-Name'
      })
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Neither on the devices nor on the PC Strangely in my browser (Chrome) I still do receive the following error: XSRF check failed

Comment: According to https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/jira-architecture/authentication/form-token-handling I updated the code to:`headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck',
          'xsrfHeaderName': 'X-Atlassian-Token',
          'xsrfCookieName': 'atlassian.xsrf.token'
        }` However this does not work.

Comment: try: `'xsrfCookieName': 'nocheck'` or even try `'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'` where is `no-check` instead of `nocheck`

Comment: Thanks. This still does not work in the browser (PC). On the device (android / ios) A different error message is returned. I am unsure if it is still the XSRF problem:

Comment: message: "Expected authority at index 7: file://"
stack-trace: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected authority at index 7: file://↵ at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)↵ at com.atlassian.applinks.core.auth.cors.DefaultCorsService.getApplicationLinksByOrigin(DefaultCorsService.java:56)↵ at com.atlassian.applinks.core.auth.cors.AppLinksCorsDefaults.allowsOrigin(AppLinksCorsDefaults.java:40)↵ at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter$1.apply(XsrfResourceFilter.java:226)↵ at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter
.
status-code:500

Comment: I think you need provide this XSRF token as mentioned [HERE](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/writing-confluence-plugins/form-token-handling). Check `Providing the token in AJAX calls` section

Comment: I think this is a similar problem: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32515329/mobile-hybrid-application-throwing-500-error-on-all-posts-after-update-to-jira-7